# Alternate access mapping is not working properly?

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, central-administration, alternate-access-mapping

I configured alternate access mapping in SharePoint 2013 with my machine IP while accessing the site collection using IP it's working fine on the Internet explore, but in chrome, images are not loaded. In console it throws an error message **404 unauthorized**, I configured for intranet like these

**Central Admin -> System settings ->  configure alternate access mappings**

[image]
I don't why Please suggest me some idea to solve this issue.

Comment: May I know the steps you followed to configure Alternate access mapping?

Comment: All images? Is it possible that resources are from different site? What is their url?

Comment: are you using the same user account in chrome ? is it worked before configuring AAM ? should you post the current AAM configuration ?

Comment: ya same user account in chrome ,its worked before AAM @Qassas

Comment: No only few images. some images are in layouts 15 and site assets @ grisha